# Migrating vue 1 to vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nouislider

I've got a working script that runs fine under Vue 1.x but it doesn't work with Vue 2.x even though I have replaced ready by mounted

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <input id="slider-input" v-model="third" v-on:change="updateSlider"/>
    <input id="slider-input" v-model="fourth" v-on:change="updateSlider"/>
</div>
```

Vue 1.x:

```
    var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    first: 3,
    second: 2,
    third: 40,
    fourth: 60,
    slider: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      start: [50, 60],
      step: 1
    },
    Slider: document.getElementById('slider')
  },
  computed: {
    total: function total() {
      return parseInt(this.first) * parseInt(this.second) * parseInt(this.third);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateSlider: function updateSlider() {
      this.Slider.noUiSlider.set(this.third);
    }
  },
  ready: function ready() {
    noUiSlider.create(this.Slider, {
      start: this.slider.start,
      step: this.slider.step,
      range: {
        'min': this.slider.min,
        'max': this.slider.max
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Now I have replaced *ready* with *mounted* and it's still not working. Problem is, it doesn't even spit out an error message in the console.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `<div id="slider">` in the template is being replaced with a different element instance once Vue has compiled the full template and rendered itself (after mounting). What I mean is, in the `mounted` hook, `this.Slider` and `document.getElementById('slider')` no longer refer to the same element (`this.Slider` is removed from the DOM).

There's probably no reason for `Slider` to be defined within the `data` block (it needn't be reactive), just initialize that in the `mounted` hook instead:

```js
mounted() {
  this.Slider = document.getElementById('slider')
  noUiSlider.create(this.Slider, ...)
}
```

Actually, a better way would be to use `ref` to get an instance of the element instead of querying the DOM:

```vue
<div ref="slider"></div>
```

```js
mounted() {
  noUiSlider.create(this.$refs.slider, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because mounted does not support functions, you had to create the functions in methods and just call it from mounted.